How to allow and/or configure rules for self-closing tags?
I am using ESLint in my Angular application. When I run ng lint which is running the following script:
    "lint": "eslint --color --fix --ext .ts ./src/app",

it fails with error:
/Users/xxxxx/FolderName/my-app/src/app/app.component.html
  1:4  error  Parsing error: '>' expected

This is related to the following rule being executed behind the scenes:
"@angular-eslint/template/prefer-self-closing-tags": [
  "error"
]

I have been searching, but it seems to be not configurable. Where could I edit/configure this rule?
Angular version:
Angular CLI: 18.0.6
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 18.0.5

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1800.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   18.0.6
@angular-devkit/core            18.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      18.0.6
@angular/cli                    18.0.6
@schematics/angular             18.0.6

Installed ESLint version and related packages:
"eslint": "^8.52.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.8.2",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
...
"@angular-eslint/builder": "^18.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^18.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^18.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.0.1",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^18.0.1",
...
enter code here
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^6.9.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.0",


both <img /> and <img> mean the same thing in html 5 - why not remove the /

@DanielA.White, I did. Error remains same. I have to mention that the tag used is not the standard HTML 5 Tag. It's an angular custom/child component which is embedded in the parent component.  Example: <app-side-navi />
